# How to disable "This Connection is Untrusted" Certificate in FireFox?

Tags: firefox

I have some 700+ links to check and they are a long links from sites. They are trusted but FireFox doesn't recognize them as trusted. So how do I disable "This Connection is Untrusted" or add a bulk of links fast to trusted ?

Comment: Does this help? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this addon, it should do what you want: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error/

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be happening due to Kaspersky or another security program which was blocking HTTPS websites due to a certificate related issue.

This untrusted connection issue might appear if you are using a 64-bit version of Mozilla Firefox along with Kaspersky security suite. Since Firefox 64-bit version is very new, there is no support for it yet in Kaspersky program. That's why it might show that error message when you try to open HTTPS websites in Firefox 64-bit version.

If you are also using Mozilla Firefox 64-bit version and Kaspersky antivirus or Internet security suite in your computer, you might also face this problem. If you face this problem, you can try following solutions:

**SOLUTION 1:**

Since 64-bit version of Firefox is not yet supported by Kaspersky, you can try to uninstall Firefox 64-bit and then install the regular 32-bit version of Firefox and your problem will be solved.

**SOLUTION 2:**

If you want to keep using 64-bit version of Firefox, then you'll need to manually install Kaspersky antivirus root certificate in Firefox to fix this issue.

Follow these simple steps:

1. Open Firefox Preferences window and go to Advanced section. Now click on Certificates tab.
2. Under Certificates tab, click on "View Certificates" button.

[image]

3. It'll open Firefox Certificate Manager window. In Authorities tab, click on Import button.

[image]

It'll open a browse window to select the file containing CA certificate to import.

4. Now copy following path and paste it in the addressbar or file name text box of the browse window:

   C:\ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab\AVP16.0.0\Data\Cert
5. Now press Enter key and the browse window will open Cert folder. Now select "(fake)Kaspersky Anti-Virus Personal Root Certificate.cer" file and click on Open button.

[image]

6. Firefox will show a confirmation window, enable all 3 checkboxes present in the window such as Trust this CA to identify websites, email users and software developers.

[image]

Now click on OK button to apply changes.

That's it. Now try to open Google and other HTTPS websites and Firefox will open them fine without any problem.

For detailed information please have a look at [[Fix] “This Connection is Untrusted” Problem with Google and Other HTTPS Websites in Mozilla Firefox](http://www.askvg.com/fix-this-connection-is-untrusted-problem-with-google-and-other-https-websites-in-mozilla-firefox/).