# Fiddlercore is not able Capture the traffic for HTTPS in Firefox V 41?

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I was trying to capture the HTTP/HTTPS Traffic in Firefox using Fiddlercore but i am getting the error "**This Connection is Untrusted**".
i had tried to change the proxy setting to the Use System Proxy and added the FiddlerCore Certificate even though i am getting "**This Connection is Untrusted**" [This is the Error I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7cdd.png)

Comment: remove certificate from settings and see if it works , your certificate generated by fiddler is not trusted.

Comment: Yeah i tried this one but when i remove the certificate the fiddler core is not able to capture the traffic for either HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: you can view http traffic without adding certificate , when you want to decrypt https traffic then only you need , make sure in left-bottom corner its set to **Capturing**

Comment: @RaviKanth For fixing the issue, you might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

My other answer is still relevant so I'm posting a new one.

I came across updated information in regards to this issue.  It is due to a Fiddler update.  Explanation here from Fiddler's author: http://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/

To fix:
**Fiddler 4.6.1.5+**

> 1. Click Tools > Fiddler Options.
> 2. Click the HTTPS tab.
> 3. Ensure that the text says Certificates generated by CertEnroll engine.
> 4. Click Actions > Reset Certificates. This may take a minute.
> 5. Accept all prompts

That page also has instructions for how to reset scripts for older versions of Fiddler.

After resetting Fiddler's certificates, I then had to configure Firefox to trust Fiddler's cert again (see Trusting the Certificate section [here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler)).

Answer (score 1):

The key here is this statement:

> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible
>   to add an exception for this certificate.

You could try removing the header in Fiddler [rules](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) by inserting this line in the OnPeekAtResponseHeaders function.

```
oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Strict-Transport-Security");
```

You would also need to remove any existing HSTS settings already in the browser. Instructions can be found [here](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers)

or just use Chrome.  It seems a little less strict in these scenarios.

Comment: I tried these steps but didn't have any luck.  After more digging, I eventually figured out that it was the Site Preferences that need to be cleared, as I explain in my answer.  Just removing the existing HSTS setting for the site I was trying to load was not sufficient because there were more login domains that the page used...so I would have also had to remove the login domains as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had Fiddler enabled and was trying to connect to a Dynamics CRM page online--something that has always worked--and I kept getting the same issue.

The only workaround I've found to be successful so far is:

1. Make sure the Fiddler cert is imported into Firefox (see "Trusting the Certificate" [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd0s9.png))
2. Press Ctrl + Shift + Del and delete all Site Preferences for time range: Everything as shown. Note that this also clears other site preferences such as site-specific permissions or zoom levels. [image]

   This is required because Firefox stores HSTS information in the Site Preferences.

Another workaround for my scenario is to just use IE.

Comment: For those wondering, the "'Trusting the Certificate' here" link above is supposed to take you to http://www.telerik.com/blogs/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler