# How to install Fiddler certificates for Firefox?

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I use the following code to install the certificates using `FiddlerCore.dll`

```
    public static bool InstallCertificate()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certmakerBcCert))
        {
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", certmakerBcKey);
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", certmakerBcCert);
        }

        if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists())
        {
            //CLog.writeNoLogInDB("Creating SSL certificate");
            if (!CertMaker.createRootCert())
                return false;

            if (!CertMaker.trustRootCert())
                return false;

            certmakerBcCert = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null);
            certmakerBcKey = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", null);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, they don't seem to install in Firefox...

So I need to install a certificate in firefox using the procedure in this post from Polshgiant for it to work.

[Fiddlercore is not able Capture the traffic for HTTPS in Firefox V 41?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361065/fiddlercore-is-not-able-capture-the-traffic-for-https-in-firefox-v-41)

My problem is that the application I'm making needs to be user friendly... So all the steps done in the post I joined, is there a way to ensure they are done in the code I pasted above?