# This Connection is Untrusted issue

Tags: security

I get the following error message.

You have asked Firefox to connect securely to www.gstatic.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.

This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

www.gstatic.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates.
An additional root certificate may need to be imported.

(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

Can someone please help me to solve this issue :'(

Comment: Firefox contains information about the valid Google certificates (certificate pinning directly on source code level). If Firefox says they are invalid someone has hacked your Internet connection.

Comment: @Volka You might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving this error message because the certificate for the site isn't valid. In order to communicate using SSL with a site, the site must provide a valid certificate. There are a number of things necessary for a valid certificate, but one factor is the certificate must be issued by a trusted certificate authority, or CA. Your browser is preconfigured with a set of trusted CAs, but for this particular site, the issuer is not part of that set of trusted authorities.

Furthermore, since the site is using HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security), an exception cannot be made for this certificate.

You'll need to view the certificate and see who issued the certificate (the CA) and whether that is a real CA. The certificate may be self-signed, which means the site issued their own certificate without a trusted CA. If you wish to continue, you'll have to install the issuer's certificate as a trusted CA in your browser. However, **do not install the issuer's certificate if you cannot verify their identity as a trusted CA.**

[This article on your particular error](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/certificate-not-trusted-error.htm) may provide guidance on why you're seeing this message. [Here's a general description](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) on how SSL works and what roles certificates and CAs play.

Comment: how can I remove this untrusted thing? :)

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the first solution, if you end up having to install a CA cert into your Firefox browser, click Edit Trust and check the "This certificate can identify websites" checkbox. If that checkbox is not checked, then Firefox will still not trust websites who issue certificates signed by that CA.