# SSL certificate: "This Connection is Untrusted" notification when www added

Tags: php, ssl, dns, server

When open my site in browser without www (https://nutritionmedicine.org.au/) it totally works fine but when i add www (https://www.nutritionmedicine.org.au/) the i got the "This Connection is Untrusted" issue.

Comment: Is not related to programming, i.e. off-topic. A better forum is serverfault.com. But a hint: the certificate contains the name without www but not the `www.*` name.

Comment: @Haroon For fixing the issue, you might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...